5 Gold Bags Problem (variant of the two envelope problem)
Here with a variant of the 2 envelopes problem that I seem to find many solutions to that are completely contradictory.
There are five bags 10, 20, 40, 80, 160 gold coins, respectively. Two bags are selected
randomly, with the constraint that one of the two bags contains twice as main coins as the
other (otherwise said, the two bags are, with the same probability, the bags containing 10
and 20 coins, or those containing 20 and 40, or 40 and 80, or 80 and 160 coins). The two
selected bags are then assigned to two players (each player gets one of the two bags with
equal probability). After seeing the contents of her bag – but not the content of the other
bag – each player is asked if she wants to switch bag with the other player. If both want to
switch, the exchange occurs.
This is just the envelope paradox rewritten, and finite. I've reached multiple solutions that are contradictory.
Firstly, either I fix the value in the two bags as U, so the two bags can either have 2U/3 or U/3 and the expected payout is 0.
Secondly, I can write that if I find U in my bag, there is an equal probability of the other bag having 2U or U/2, with an expected payout of 5U/4.
Thirdly, by backwards induction from 160, no one wants to switch (if I have 160 I won't switch, so the person who gets 80 won't switch knowing the one with 160 would never switch, thus switching only makes him potentially lose money to a person with 40.
Fourthly: we could say for example that the pairs (10,20) and (20,40) are equally likely pairs. If I as a player pick 20 and always swap, I can either get 0 if the opposing player doesn’t swap, and -10 or +20 if he swaps, which is an expected payout of +5.
So with 4 approaches that I think are all logically fine, I get different payouts and different equilibriums. I know this is supposed to be a paradox but I believe the finite edition has an answer, so what gives?
The original question is to find the Bayesian Nash Equilibrium.
Thanks a lot!

For the second one, for example, that computation does not work at the extremes.  If you have $10$ then you know that you gain if you switch, and if you have $160$ then you know that you lose.  For the fourth, you neglect the fact that your opponent may change their action based on the value they hold.

As you point out, with $80$ player $A$ never switches, because if player $B$ has $160$, they will never switch. So switching can never gain.
Similar logic applies if $A$ has $40$: assuming $B$ is playing sensibly, they will never switch with $80$, so again, switching can never gain.
The same applies if $A$ has $20$: switching can never gain, because if $B$ has $40$, they won't want to switch.
To sum up: never switch! (If you have $10$, you might as well choose to switch, but it won't get you anything, because $B$ won't be switching.)
